# location values are null with facebook API in android

Tags: java, android, facebook, api, location

I'm trying to make a simple app where the only thing i want to retrieve are the coordinates of my current position, using facebook user's data.
I'm following this guide to get started with this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

The only difference is where I substituted

```
user.getName();
```

with

```
user.getLocation().getLatitude(); //it's always null and so throws exception.
```

then i tried other methods like getCountry() or getState(); the value is always null.

Anybody knows how to fix this and get the location values using these methods? Thanks.

Here is my portion of code:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

     // callback when session changes state

     @Override
     public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
     if (session.isOpened()) {
      // make request to the /me API
      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

       // callback after Graph API response with user object

       @Override
       public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (user != null) {
         TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
         txt.setText("Latitude is: " + user.getLocation().getLatitude());
        }
       }
      });

     }
   }
 });
}
```

edit: in the hackbook project sample which comes with the facebook sdk, I see that's possible to get coordinates (latitude and longitude) by the location ID, anyone knows how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I finally have the answer: to get coordinates from ID I used this query:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/ID
```

then just parse the result to get the coordinates (correct me if there's an easier way please)
Where the ID is easily gettable with:

```
user.getLocation();
```

By the way in my first try I still don't know why the values returned were null, maybe my workaround's result isn't as accurate as I thought, but I realize that facebook doesn't register a so accurate location when somebody post something to his wall, but just coordinates of the city from which the post comes from. (again, correct me if I'm wrong please).

Thank you.

Comment: Well, the accuracy is a privacy matter, I think. It’s okay for me to have my friends know I posted this while being in city XY – but to I want them to know the exact address of the sex shop I’m standing in front of right now? Maybe rather not …

Comment: I am trying this ,but it only give city,State can not give country

Answer (score 3):

You have to use **getProperty** method - an example to retrieve city & country is -

```
user.getLocation().getProperty("name");
```

Check the [**link**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/GraphUser/), it says -
GraphUser Provides a strongly-typed representation of a User as defined by the Graph API. Note that **this interface is intended to be used with GraphObject.Factory and not implemented directly**.

This [**link**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/fetch-user-data/#prerequisities) has some examples, that will make things clearer.

I quote this from here - Some of the data in this response can be accessed as strongly typed properties of the properties of the GraphUser interface - example: ***name*** and ***birthday***. **Other properties can be accessed by using the getProperty() method and selecting the desired key** - example: ***locale*** and ***languages***. This step shows you how to access the user's name, birthday, languages, location and locale.

Answer (score 0):

getLocation() method returns only the current city of the user.